# Why add and subtract 1000 for hough line transformation?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, computer-vision

Here is some code from a tutorial. Why do we add 1000 and subtract 1000, and why is b negative?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('sudoku.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi /180, 200)

for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0  = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho

    x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))

    x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: i think it's just scaling them?

Answer (score 2):

In Python/OpenCV HoughLines, it is to define the endpoints of the lines so that they go to (and past) the sides of the image when drawing the lines. The hough transform you have used only returns the angle and distance from the original for the lines. So the extra computation finds the intersection of a line from the origin perpendicular to the line, so that it can identify some point on the line. But it does not know how long the line should be. So it extends the line by this much from that point along the line. Since it knows the angle of the line and a point on the line, it just provides a distance for the two end points from the given point on the line. If your image is larger than about 2*1000 pixels in dimension, then you may need to increase the 1000 value if you want the lines to go to the sides of the image.

The minus sign (-b) occurs as follows:

The direction from the origin in a direction perpendicular to the line is given by its slope `b/a = sin(theta)/cos(theta)=tan(theta)`. See the diagram at https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html. But the direction of the line itself is 90 deg from that and its angle is given by `-1/tan(theta) = -cos(theta)/sin(theta) = -a/b or a/-b`. That is its slope is (a/-b)=(y-yo)/(x-xo)=delY/delX. See https://byjus.com/maths/slope-of-line/. So to get the two end points you can start at any point as given by xo, yo and go along the line in either direction, so that the end point X component is xo +- 1000*delX = xo +- 1000*cos(perp_angle) = xo +- 1000*(-b) and the end point Y component is yo +- 1000*delY = yo +- 1000*sin(perp_angle) = yo +- 1000*a. Where perp_angle is the direction along the actual line.

Comment: aha! That makes sense. But why is b negative?

Comment: See my additions in my answer above.